# Photon travelling in a loop

Tags: visible-light

I am wondering how my concept of light is flawed. Am I right in supposing that when I look at a star the light that I see is only the specific photons which enter my eyes? That means I never see the same image twice, nobody else sees the same thing I do and the photons which enter my eyes become pretty much lost inside me, interacting with other particles which make up the "me". I pondered the case where a hypothetical (and probably rare) circumstance sets up a photon to travel in a tight loop. If nothing interfered with the photon it could come as close as possible to my eye and I would never see it, right? Also, the questions I am embarrassed to ask but must ... does light ever function as a medium and can light support weight?

Comment: If the sun disappeared how could the planets continue in their orbits?  They need the gravity of the sun.

Comment: @ggcg - yeah true, sorry. I guess I would need an invisible gravity source in my case - thanks

Comment: *'Light does have a tiny mass though since [...]"* That does not follow for your suggested reasoning. The theory works perfectly well with massless light. The light has *energy*.

Comment: @Wookie Light has energy without having any mass. Its energy is entirely contained in, and described by, its momentum.

Comment: @Wookie I would suggest looking up "does light have mass?"

Comment: By “does light ever function as a medium”, do you mean can light transport a wave like water does?

Comment: @mmesser314 - I've probably formulated it wrong but I considered that light is slowed by entering water so I wondered if anything would be affected by entering light?

Comment: You can get a suntan. Light is energy. If you absorb the energy, you might get hot. On the other hand, if you are perfectly transparent, it doesn’t affect you at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

" Am I right in supposing that when I look at a star the light that I see is only the specific photons which enter my eyes?"

The answer to this question is Yes.

---

"That means I never see the same image twice, nobody else sees the same thing I do and the photons which enter my eyes become pretty much lost inside me, interacting with other particles which make up the "me"."

Well, no. An image is the distribution of the number of photons which arrived to different pixels in space in a certain time (for the human eye it is about a couple of tens of milliseconds). Meaning if you send the same number of photons with the same spatial distribution you will produce the same image. You are correct that the moment they reach your eyes they are destroyed, but photons aren't distinguishable (if they have the same frequency, polarization, and spatial frequency).

---

"If nothing interfered with the photon it could come as close as possible to my eye and I would never see it, right?"

What do you mean? I didn't get what you asked, but you won't see a photon if it doesn't hit your retina (the back part of your eye).

---

"Also, the questions I am embarrassed to ask".

No, ask anything, don't be shy! Curiosity is great and should be encouraged!

---

"does light ever function as a medium"

What do you mean, a medium for what?

---

"can light support weight?"

Yes, this is called radiation pressure. The force a light beam with power P can deliver is $\frac{P}{c}$ where $c$ is the speed of light. To support a particle with a mass of $m$ against gravity you need to apply a force of $mg$, so for a given light beam you can calculate how light (ba dum tss) does a particle have to be for light to support it.

Comment: Well, thank you Ofek, you answered my questions. Yes, I meant if the photon itself does not hit my retina I would not perceive it visually. I have been corrected a little in the comments above but I basically wondered if something (similar to neutrinos for example) could be slowed down by entering a light-stream (as a medium).

Comment: Light isn't a medium, but because it can apply a force, it can stop particles made of electric charge. This is important, because the essence of light is a wave in the electric and magnetic fields, meaning it can only affect directly charged particles. This is used to stop and cool down atoms (which have a negatively charged electron and a positive nucleus). However, they can't affect neutrinos at all because they are neutral